# GMailSender on Android causing Relay Access Denied Error

Tags: java, android, email, gmail

I have a app through which you can send a email. This is done using the following code. The sender account is an GMail account:

```
GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("sender@gmail.com", "APassword");
sender.sendMail(subject,
                emailText[0],
                "sender@gmail.com",
                receiver);
```

The receiver varies for testing reasons, but should be static when the app is released. Now I started testing by sending mails to another GMail account, which works fine. I continued to send mails to an outlook account, also works great. When I send emails to a private email server though, I get the following message back:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> booking@reciever.de
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain
>   reciever.de by mail.reciever.de. [88.198.227.52].
>
> The error that the other server returned was: 554 5.7.1
>   : Recipient address rejected: Relay access denied

I tried to figure out what this error is about, yet I have not completely understood it. I guess GMail doesn't like the receiver domain and thus does not send the email.(?)

How can I get GMail to ignore it and send it anyway? Or what else can I do to send the email? I would also greatly appreciate if someone could elaborate on this error, it is not much or well explained on the internet yet.

Comment: Does this happen only when sending email through your app, or also when using Gmail's normal web interface ? If it happens when unsing the normal Gmail interface, there's probably not much you can do about it.

Comment: Good point, I had not tried it yet... But it happens sending it through gmail.com as well as inbox.google.com, and I get the same return message back... But there has to be some kind of workaround... I mean I'd like to send a email to a email adress... shouldn't be that big of a problem :(

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is not on your end, but on the receiving end (Does the email address you're sending to exist / work ?). Otherwise I don't know what else could be wrong, sorry.

Comment: It does exist and there are emails coming in daily... I think they are all sent from the same email adress though, so there could be (but should not be, according to the owner) a whitelist... As far as I understood the error though it should be a problem on my side. Thanks for your help anyways! ;)